# Role of processing bodies in mammalian development

Tags: development

I am currently writing a project proposal for university admissions regarding the duration till which maternal mRNA is required for mammalian development. Till now all the literature I have read has data on P-bodies during oogenesis:-
1) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22918798/
2) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2785738/
It will be very helpful if anyone can provide a link for research articles showing p-bodies during embryogenesis in mammals.

Comment: These papers might be helpful. 

http://www.molbiolcell.org/content/19/10/4383.short
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1874939913000047

Comment: @Divyanshumishra Thanks. I will go through them.